# How to use multithreading concept for Struts2 web application?

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2

I am having a web application with Struts2 framework. I have a class which has a number of methods, out of which one is

```
  private void callMethod()
    {
      setUnreadReceiptCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "receipt",Constants.Open));
        setWorklistFilesCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "file","worklist"));
       mp=wrapper.getFileWorklist(us,stat,"","","",Constants.FilterbyFileReceivedDate,Constants.sortOrderDsc,next,10);
     }
```

I want that all the three calls inside the method should be done using three different threads . Please explain how to do so.

Comment: struts2 does not have any special relevance here. You need simple multi-threading code.

Comment: when it will be invoked- as a part of HTTP request?

Comment: Okay, so please answer how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You may simply want to spin off three threads in Java to do this.

Comment: Please tell is there any way to do this. Yes, i want three threads to perform three different tasks. But, i am completely new to it, so please help.

Comment: Here is some resource to threads. Hope it  helps !! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html